Perform time consuming disposal asynchronously
Imagine having a class that does some stuff and displays the results in modal window.
The class has a costly dispose, i.e. it has to free resources which may take some seconds.
The problem: When I close the window, I call the dispose method to free all the objects. This results in the window freezing for some seconds before closing. I want to avoid that.
Research brought me to IAsyncDisposable. My working implementation looks like this:
    public class MyClass : IAsyncDisposable, IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposedValue;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // Disposing some costly stuff
                }
                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(disposing: true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(Dispose);
        }
    }

Calling it via:
myClassInstance.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Question: Is this valid, especially the implementation of the DisposeAsync method? Can something go wrong here? It works nicely, but I am somehow not convinced.
I did some research on this but did not find anybody that did it this way.
Even more, Visual Studio tells me that I should do something with the ValueTask I get from calling the DisposeAsync method. Any comments on that?

Why would anything freeze if you are not awaiting your dispose?

Well afaik, Dispose is just a method. When I call it, it is a synchronous call. If something in Dispose takes a lot of time, it effectively blocks the calling thread. As it is called in the thread of the view (window), it freezes the window.

That might work as long as you don't care about lost exceptions.

"Visual Studio tells me ..." - what it tells you?

async and concurrency are related but fundamentally different things; you're trying to solve something with async but that isn't the problem - you can just dispose this as a background operation without adding or removing anything async - Task.Run or ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem would work without needing async / IAsyncDisposable.

So there is no await before the myClassInstance.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);?

@Sinatr: Hint CA2012 , so there is also no await before the call of DisposeAsync.

@MarcGravell possibly it's done that way so that he can control when to dispose synchronously and when to dispose in the background?

Implement a DisposeAsync method

as a nit: it sounds like your plan is to not await obj.DisposeAsync() - but: for 100% correct operation, it is required to await (or at least observe) every ValueTask / ValueTask<T> exactly once (not zero times, not twice etc; this is because of how IValueTaskSource / IValueTaskSource<T> works (which is a niche API, and most value-tasks won't be using it, but the point is that it is an implementation detail that the caller doesn't know about)

@MarkCiliaVincenti you don't need DisposeAsync for that

@MarcGravell That makes sense, I just thought I follow the IAsyncDisposable interface as MS provides this.

@MarkCiliaVincenti "dispose in the background" is not the same as "dispose asynchronously" - this code massively conflates the two in ways that are not helpful; using Task.Run to run something does not make it asynchronous in any way that matters here

@Philipp but you're not following IAsyncDisposable; to do that, you are required to await the disposal, which means your app would still be blocked; async isn't about avoiding delays that might (for example) block a UI; it is about allowing the CPU to do useful unrelated work while blocked, and that isn't the issue here. If you want to do something in the background: just do that thing in the background

@MarcGravell Yes I know it's not the same in technical terms, but going by an English dictionary definition, it's pretty much what it is, hence why there is this confusion. For the sake of doing things the right way, though, he should revise how he's doing things.

@MarcGravell That is a useful hint, thanks for the clarification. I am sure that I red such a statement already somewhere but somehow it always doesn't stay to long in my mind. I will probably write it to a sticky note and put it on my screen....

"regular" english dictionaries are rarely useful when discussing how terms are used in any specific specialized technical context ;p (and I'm not limiting that to programming)

@MarcGravell I know right? Unfortunately, I think that in general the choice of wording for asynchronous code leaves this ambiguity that's way too easy for people to misunderstand how it works.

If you want to dispose something in the background (and that disposal is inherently synchronous), just dispose it in the background; for example instead of:
obj.Dispose();

consider:
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem<IDisposable>(static s => s.Dispose(), obj, false);

Ultimately asynchronous and concurrent are related but different concepts; in this case what we want is concurrency, and async is unrelated - no need (or purpose) to add or remove it.
